# Unexpected behaviour for evaluation metrics (precision etc) in sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
a = [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 ]
b = [ 1, 2, 2, 1, 1 ]

print precision_score(a,b, labels = [1])
# 0.6666
print precision_score(a,b, labels = [2])
# 0.5
print precision_score(a,b, labels = [1,2])
# 0.6666
```

Why are the values same for the first and last case?

Calculating by hand, total precision should be 3/5 = 0.6. But the third case outputs 0.6666, which happens to be the value of the first one.

Edit 1: Added the import path to the function in question.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell `precision_score` for which label it should compute the precision. What you're seeing is the precision for label `1`:

```
>>> precision_score(a, b)
0.66666666666666663
>>> precision_score(a, b, pos_label=1)
0.66666666666666663
```

But you want the precision for label `2`:

```
>>> precision_score(a, b, pos_label=2)
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

See here (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_score) for documentation. I think you need to change the *average* argument to *micro* to get the overall precision across the specified labels i.e.:

```
print precision_score(a,b, labels = [1,2], average='micro')
```

The default value for *average* is *weighted*, which computes a weighted average of precision over the specified labels. If you use *micro*, according to the documentation, it computes the precision over all true and false positives (presumably *all* means all the specified labels, but the documentation is not clear on this). I think this is what you want? I have not been able to check this, as I don't know which version of *scikit* you're using.

Comment: You're on the right track. I do want to compute precision over all true/false positives. But "average='micro'" still gives me the same results (0.66666) instead of 0.6. Let me upgrade my scikit installation and try it again.